# Backbone wants to include created_at, updated_at, etc., but I don't want it to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone with Rails. I have a model that I can create and destroy just fine. When I edit, though, I get this error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: created_at, id, updated_at
```

That makes sense. Those attributes are protected and they should be protected. Backbone shouldn't be trying to update these attributes, but Backbone doesn't know better.

One option, of course, would be to remove `params[:created_at]`, etc. in my Rails controller, but I can imagine that getting really un-DRY pretty quick, and plus it just seems wrong to have to do that.

Is there a way for me to tell Backbone not to include these attributes in its forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either don't send them to the client so that your Backbone model never knows about them or override [`toJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) in your model to exclude them.

The default `toJSON` implementation is very simple:

```
toJSON: function() {
    return _.clone(this.attributes);
}
```

so you can replace it with this:

```
toJSON: function() {
    var attrs = _(this.attributes).clone();
    delete attrs.created_at;
    delete attrs.updated_at;
    return attrs;
}
```

You could even monkey patch that right into `Backbone.Model.prototype` if that made sense to you.

The downside of altering `toJSON` is that `toJSON` tends to do double duty in Backbone:

1. `toJSON` is used to serialize models and collections for the server.
2. `toJSON` is used to serialize models and collections for views.

If you still want to use `updated_at` and `created_at` in views then I'd recommend adding another method, say `serialize_for_view`, that does what the standard `toJSON` does:

```
serialize_for_view: function() {
    return _(this.attributes).clone();
}
```

and then use things like `var html = this.template({m: this.model.serialize_for_view()})` to build your view's HTML. You could also monkey patch `serialize_for_view` into `Backbone.Model.prototype` if you wanted to use it everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I found that putting

```
model.unset("created_at");
model.unset("updated_at");
model.save()
```

fixed the problem. This won't work if you need those attributes, but if they are not needed, this works.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer to the question - but rather a "me-too" type comment.

Comment: Yes, my apologies for that. To make up for the noise, a bit of signal: I found that putting `model.unset("created_at")` and then `model.unset("updated_at")` before `model.save()` fixed the problem. This won't work if you need those attributes, but if they are not needed, this works.

Comment: Please [edit] to add signal, and flag to have this undeleted when done.